# Does anybody have computed a Poisson-loss on Lasso/Ridge Regression?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, regression

I am new with scikit learn, and I am looking for some code to compute the Poisson loss. Instead of the mean square error :

```
(y_hat - y)**2
```

I would like :

```
2*(y*log(y/y_hat) - (y-y_hat))
```

Can I find a Github or some stuff that does it ?

Comment: We need some more information to understand your problem.

Comment: This site is for programming questions. We are not here to find software/code for you. And keep the language clean.

Answer (score 0):

I think he's searching an equivalent of R-package "penalized" but in Python. A penalized regression where you can specify that your residual follows a poisson distribution